# ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was editing my `wordpress` page and I didn't do anything unusual, but suddenly my HomePage lost background color (Now borders are white but the middle of the page is how it should be).

My console keeps throwing me this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ajax-filter-posts.js?ver=1:57)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)

at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)

at Object.trigger (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)

at Object.a.event.trigger (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)

at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)

at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)

at a.fn.init.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)

at a.fn.init.trigger (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (ajax-filter-posts.js?ver=1:76)
```

what to do? My **ajax-filter-posts.js?ver=1:57** looks like this:

```
(function($) {
$doc = $(document);
$doc.ready( function() {
    /*Retrieve posts*/
    var container = $('.container-async');
    container.each(function() {
        var $movie_tab_id = $(this).attr('id'),
            $movie_tab = "#" + $movie_tab_id,
            $content = $($movie_tab).find('.category-content.flw');
        function get_posts($params) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: blockter.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    action: 'do_filter_posts',
                    nonce: blockter.nonce,
                    params: $params
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    if (data.status === 200) {
                        $content.html(data.content);
                    }
                    else if (data.status === 201) {
                        $content.html(data.message);
                    }
                },
                error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                },
                complete: function(data, textStatus) {

                    msg = textStatus;

                    if (textStatus === 'success') {
                        msg = data.responseJSON.found;
                    }

                    $content.removeClass('loading');
                }
            });
        }

        $($movie_tab).on('click', 'button[data-filter], .category-pagination li a', function(event) {
            if(event.preventDefault) { event.preventDefault(); }
            var $this = $(this),
                $mediaType = null;
            /*Set filter active*/
            if ($this.data('filter')) {
                $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                $page = $this.data('page');
                $mediaType = $this.data('media');
                $postin = $this.data('postin');
            }
            else {
                /*Pagination*/
                $page = parseInt($this.attr('href').replace(/\D/g,''));
                $mediaType = $this.parent().data('media');
                $postin = $this.parent().data('postin');
                $this = $('.category-filter button.active');
            }
            $content.addClass('loading');
            $content.append('<div class="ajaxloading"></div>');
            $params = {
                'page' : $page,
                'tax'  : $this.data('filter'),
                'term' : $this.data('term'),
                'qty'  : $this.closest($($movie_tab)).data('paged'),
                'media': $mediaType,
                'postin': $this.data('postin'),
            };

            /*Run query*/
            get_posts($params);
        });
        $('button[data-term="all-terms"]').trigger('click');
    });

    var $movie_tab_id = $('.container-async').attr('id'),
    $movie_tab = "#" + $movie_tab_id,
    $content = $($movie_tab).find('.category-content.flw'),
    $contents = $($movie_tab).find('.category-content.specific');

    $($movie_tab).on('click', 'button[data-filter], .category-pagination li a', function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: blockter.ajax_url,
            data: {
                action: 'do_filter_posts',
                nonce: blockter.nonce,
                params: $params
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                if (data.status === 200) {
                    $content.html(data.content);
                    $contents.html(data.content);
                }
                else if (data.status === 201) {
                    $content.html(data.message);    
                    $contents.html(data.message);   
                }
            },
            error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            },
            complete: function(data, textStatus) {

                msg = textStatus;

                if (textStatus === 'success') {
                    msg = data.responseJSON.found;
                }

                $content.removeClass('loading');
                $contents.removeClass('loading');
            }
        });
        $contents.addClass('loading');
        $contents.append('<div class="ajaxloading"></div>');

    });
});

})(jQuery);
```

and it says that error is here:

```
/*Pagination*/
                $page = parseInt($this.attr('href').replace(/\D/g,''));
                $mediaType = $this.parent().data('media');
                $postin = $this.parent().data('postin');
                $this = $('.category-filter button.active');
```

Comment: also you can check my website to know about what I am talking..navigate to ''Pocetna'' and then navigate to ''Serije'' (serije is how it need to be)..it something messed up with this background color.. https://instabit.co/

Comment: Are you sure you have `href` inside your `$movie_tab`? Can you maybe share your html.

Comment: Please turn off your adblocker check if you want people from SO to check your site out. Also, the error is telling you that $this.attr('href') is undefined - so, log $this to see what it is; does it have the attr "href" ?

Comment: disabled the adblocker check..you can check again now.. sorry... Im not good at coding so I really need detailed help I think...

Comment: Checked your website, it doesn't look like you have an href inside your tabs, so that's your issue.

Comment: How can I fix that? Im sorry..Can you navigate me a bit more..@Anas

Comment: @Anas can explain me a bit more? :S

Comment: @RenatoLulic Basically, the reason why you're getting the error is that you're trying to apply `replace` on an undefined element. The undefined element here is `$this.attr('href')`. The reason it's undefined is because Jquery cannot find an href attribute inside `$this`. $this in this case is your tabs. So your tabs don't contain a link it looks like.

Comment: One of the fixes for that would be: `$page = parseInt(($this.attr('href') || '0').replace(/\D/g,''));`